# Countable Subsets of Irrational Sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

If A is an uncountable subset of the reals such that all elements of A are irrational, is there a countable subset Z of A such that for all x,y in A, there is a z in Z such that x>z>y?

In general, I want to claim that for any uncountable subset B of the reals, there is always a countable subset Y such that $\forall b,b' \in B$ such that $b>b'$, $\exists y\in Y$ such that $b>y>b'$.

Comment: No, there isn't. For instance, let $A$ be the set of all irrational numbers $x$ such that $x^2>=2$. Now take $x=+\sqrt 2, y=-\sqrt 2$. (By the way, you forgot to say that $x>y$.)

Comment: Not true, as others have pointed out, but a slight change makes it true and more interesting: $\forall b,b' \in B \setminus Y ....$

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is not always possible, because $A$ can contain points that adjacent in $A$. However, it cannot contain too many of them.

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ be uncountable. Let

$$S=\left\{x\in A:\exists y\in A\big(x<y\text{ and }(x,y)\cap A=\varnothing\big)\right\}\,,$$

the set of elements of $A$ that have immediate successors in $A$. For $s\in S$ let $s^+$ be the immediate successor of $s$ in $S$. The intervals $(s,s^+)$ for $s\in S$ must contain distinct rationals, so $S$ is countable.

$\Bbb R$ is hereditarily separable, so $A$ has a countable subset $D$ that is dense in $A$ in the subspace topology on $A$. Suppose that $x,y\in A$ and $x<y$. If $(x,y)\cap A=\varnothing$, then $x\in S$, and $y=s^+$. Otherwise, $(x,y)\cap A$ is a non-empty open subset of $A$ in the subspace topology on $A$, so there is a $z\in D$ such that $x<z<y$.

This is the best that you can do along these lines unless you begin by requiring that $A$ be densely ordered.

Comment: Thank you. I am specifically trying to show that if I have an asymmetric and negatively transitive binary relation >' on an uncountable set X and there exists a function u: X -> R such that for x,y in X, x>'y iff u(x) > u(y), then there must exist a countable order-dense subset Z of X, so that for all x,y in X with x>'y, there exists a z in Z such that x>'z>'y. My concern was if the range of u was an uncountable set of irrationals from R. So now I'm not sure.

Comment: @N.C.: Am I correct in thinking that a relation $\succ$ is negatively transitive if $x\not\succ y$ and $y\not\succ z$ imply that $x\not\succ z$?

Comment: That's correct. And this is equivalent to saying that if $x\succ y$, then for all $z\in X,$ either $x\succ z$ or $z\succ y$.

Comment: @N.C.: Okay; I’ll try to give it some thought.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.

Comment: @N.C. I don't understand your initial comment: if $x$ and $y$ are successors in $X$, then regardless of what $Z$ we pick there is no $z\in Z$ between $x$ and $y$. Maybe you want to say "for $x,y$ in $Z$" instead of "for $x,y$ in $X$?"

Comment: @NoahSchweber I never said they were successors.